# Remove background color/images for all elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is there a simple way to use jQuery to remove all background styles on a page? Specifically, need to remove background color and images.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Real simple with jQuery...

```
$('*').css('background', 'transparent');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HvPzu/).

If you didn't have jQuery at your disposal...

```
var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

for (var i = 0, length = allElements.length; i < length; i++) {
    allElements[i].style.background = "none";
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LeMdp/).

Comment: Here is why! Introducing the Yule Log-on Greasemonkey script: http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/92217. Happy holidays!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('*').css('background', 'transparent');
```

Comment: What are the advantages of using `'transparent'` over `'none'`?

Comment: @alex -- Apparently `transparent` is the valid property assignment here, where `none` is not valid CSS2... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739665/is-background-colornone-valid-css

Comment: @IanCampbell Interesting. `transparent` it is :)

Answer (score -1):

HTML

```
<ul>
 <li class="one"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li class="two"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li class="three"><a href="#"></a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.bg1 { background: url(images/red.jpg) repeat-x; background-color: #6c0000; }
.bg2 { background: url(images/orange.jpg) repeat-x; background-color: #5A2A00; }
.bg3 { background: url(images/blue.jpg) repeat-x; background-color: #00345B; }
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

        $("li.one").click( function(){ $
  ("body").removeClass('bg2 , bg3').addClass("bg1");
 });

 $("li.two").click( function(){ $
  ("body").removeClass("bg1 , bg3").addClass("bg2");
 });

 $("li.three").click( function(){ $
  ("body").removeClass("bg1 , bg2").addClass("bg3");
 }); 

});
```

Comment: pooja , you can format the code by using 100101 above or ctnr-k