# How can I remove a background-image attribute?

Tags: jquery, css

I have this code :

```
if (pansel.val() == "1") 
     $(#myDiv).css('background-image', 'url(/private_images/guida_check_category.jpg)'); 
else 
     $(#myDiv).css({ 'background-color': '#ffffff' });
```

and I see that, when I apply the background-image, the follow code :

```
$(#myDiv).css({ 'background-color': '#ffffff' });
```

doesnt remove the image and put the white background color. The image still present!

How can I totally remove that background-image attribute?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (pansel.val() == "1") 
     $("#myDiv").css('background-image', 'url(/private_images/guida_check_category.jpg)'); 
else {
     $("#myDiv").css({ 'background-color': '#ffffff' });
     $("#myDiv").css('background-image', 'none');
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this will not actually _remove_ the attribute, it will simply add an inline style of `background-image:none` -- see my answer if you would like to actually _remove_ the attribute

Comment: Using the dictionary syntax, both changes can be made at once via: `$("#myDiv").css({ 'background-color': '#ffffff',  'background-image': 'none'});`

Answer (score 6):

This code...

```
$myDiv = $('#myDiv');
$myDiv.css('background-image', 'none');
```

will not actually *remove* the background-image property. It will make jQuery set an inline style of 'background-image:none' to the myDiv element, which may not be what you want.

If you later apply a class to the myDiv element which uses a background image or attempt to use 'background: url('... to set a background image, the inline style will override and the background image will not show.

To remove the property, I would suggest that you just set the 'background-image' value to nothing, then it will disappear from the inline style all together and you can manipulate it much more easily...

```
if (pansel.val() === "1") {
    $myDiv.css('background-image', 'url(/private_images/guida_check_category.jpg)'); 
} else {
    $myDiv.css('background-color', '#ffffff').css('background-image', ''); 
    //the value will be set to white with the image 'empty', so it will disappear from inline styles
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`background:0` will remove the entire background css

Answer (score 1):

`$('*').css('background', 'transparent')`

see: [Remove background color/images for all elements with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384213/remove-background-color-images-for-all-elements-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to completely remove the style attribute you can do something like this

```
var oDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
oDiv.style.removeProperty("background-color");
```

I have found that setting it to transparent creates some odd conflicts, if you later do other color operations on that area. Removing the attribute works better if you are trying to revert back to some default setting specified in your css.

Answer (score 0):

`$(element).css('background-image', '')`

I don't know what is happens in backstage but img is removed from UI.