# Remove background image not working

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

I've tried all the following to remove the background image but it didn't work until I used the solution that is marked as the answer.

```
$(document.body).on("click", "#lnkFAQ", function () {

    document.getElementById("bodyContent").style.backgroundImage = '';
    document.getElementById("bodyContent").style.height = 10;

    if (document.all) {
        document.body.style.removeAttribute('background-image');
    }
    else {
        document.body.style.removeProperty('background-image');
    }

    $("#bodyContent").css("background-image",'url("")');

});
```

and the Site.css

```
/* Set padding to keep content from hitting the edges */
.body-content {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("/Content/Img/MainPageBackground.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: Did you try googling first?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747176/how-can-i-remove-a-background-image-attribute

Comment: @user1477388 Your link is excelent. Dont know how I missed it. Thanks for the information. +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#bodyContent").css("background-image",'none');
```

OR

```
$("#bodyContent").attr("style","background-image:none");
```

Comment: this one changes all style of the element not what OP asked for.