# Is background-color:none valid CSS?

Tags: css, background-color

Can anyone tell me if the following CSS is valid?

```css
.class {
    background-color:none;
}
```

Comment: The [validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input) can often answer this sort of question.

Comment: You may be confused with `background:none;`, which is valid, and which sets the background color to transparent.

Answer (score 738, accepted):

You probably want `transparent` as `none` is not a valid `background-color` value.

The [CSS 2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#propdef-background-color) states the following for the `background-color` property:

> `Value:   <color> | transparent | inherit`

`<color>` can be either a keyword or a numerical representation of a colour. [Valid `color` keywords](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-color) are:

> aqua, black, blue, fuchsia, gray, green, lime, maroon, navy, olive,
>   orange, purple, red, silver, teal, white, and yellow

`transparent` and `inherit` are valid keywords in their own right, but `none` is not.

Comment: Yes. Since the _initial value_ is `transparent`, that is what you use if you want to turn background coloring "off".

Comment: none of these will reset to a previous value (ie if set by another css rule :(

Comment: @pstanton in your case, you need to give  background-color: transparent !important;

Comment: This reminds me of trying to use font-color when I first got going with coding. Of course it's `color`, not `font-color`. Makes so much sense whenever ever other font property has `font` in front of it...

Comment: @herr But still as pstanton said, setting background color transparent would override the previous css properties! Is there any way to remove this background colour property such that it takes the CSS property from the previous one?

Comment: element.style.backgroundColor = "";

Answer (score 192):

No, use `transparent` instead `none` . See working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/89Cqe/)  in this example if you will change `transparent` to `none` it will not work

use like `.class { background-color:transparent; }`

---

Where **.class** is what you will name your transparent class.

Comment: In my example it's complete opposite. If you change none to transparent it will not work. I really need to use none: http://jsfiddle.net/BkAad/

Comment: In your example, change to    body *:not(.exception){ 
    background-color:transparent
}

You must remove the !important as that is forcing all the others inside to have that property.

And on the inside li(s) rather use the background-color property than the background's one for background color alone.

Answer (score 122):

The answer is no.

### Incorrect

```css
.class {
    background-color: none; /* do not do this */
}
```

### Correct

```css
.class {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

`background-color: transparent` accomplishes the same thing what you wanted to do with `background-color: none`.

Answer (score 17):

CSS Level 3 specifies the `unset` property value. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset):

> The unset CSS keyword is the combination of the initial and inherit
>   keywords. Like these two other CSS-wide keywords, it can be applied to
>   any CSS property, including the CSS shorthand all. This keyword resets
>   the property to its inherited value if it inherits from its parent or
>   to its initial value if not. In other words, it behaves like the
>   inherit keyword in the first case and like the initial keyword in the
>   second case.

Unfortunately this value is currently not supported in all browsers, including IE, Safari and Opera. I suggest using `transparent` for the time being.

Comment: Hey, `unset` has since [become **fully supported**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset) in all browsers that aren't IE!

Answer (score 13):

```css
.class {
    background-color:none;
}
```

This is not a valid property. W3C validator will display following error:

> Value Error : background-color none is not a background-color value : none

`transparent` may have been selected as better term instead of `0` or `none` values during the development of specification of CSS.

Comment: And this repeats what James said two and a half years ago, but in a non-cut and pasteable format. ;^)

Answer (score 3):

So, I would like to explain the scenario where I had to make use of this solution. Basically, I wanted to undo the background-color attribute set by another CSS. The expected end result was to make it look as though the original CSS had never applied the background-color attribute . Setting `background-color:transparent;` made that effective.

Comment: I'm finding that background:transparent is not working for me to override a background color being set by another css. If I choose background:red; for example - that will work. But background:transparent; is allowing the other css background color to remain. Any ideas how to stop that?

Answer (score 1):

write this:

```
.class {
background-color:transparent;
}
```

Comment: Please explain your code and how it helps to solve the problem! - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/19714670)

Comment: Ok. background-color is a css attribute and like every css attribute can have some valid and non valid value. valid value for  background-color can be one of the below format: #5f9 or #56f293 or transparent. transparent means you want null or none background color.

Comment: wow - 6 year after the question (and the answer) you answer with a duplicate?