# how do I override user agent -- using buttons from angularjs

Tags: css, angularjs, sass, user-agent

I can't seem to override the user agent CSS settings, even when I use `!`.

I have buttons as links and use AngularJS.  I added a screenshot below:

Notice how even with `!` I cannot override the `background-color`.

I am using sass and haml for my view.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`none` is not a valid value for `background-color`, but it is a valid value for the `background` shorthand. The mixup comes from it being seemingly natural to think that the `none` value in the shorthand sets `background-color`, but it actually refers to the `background-image` property.

Use `background-color: transparent` instead.

[Is background-color:none valid CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739665/is-background-colornone-valid-css)