# In css, how can I set background of one class to none while keeping the background of another class?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following bootstrap HTML:

```
<div class='input-group'>
    <input class='form-control' /> 
    <span class='input-group-addon btn btn-primary'><i class='fa fa-chevron-down'></i></span> 
</div>
```

The input-group-addon has a background-image set that is overriding the btn-primary image, so it shows as grey instead of my btn-primary color.

I thought this css would fix it:

```
.input-group .input-group-addon:not(.btn-primary) {
    background-color: none;
}
```

but it doesn't seem to be working.  When I look at the element in chrome, this style doesn't even show up.

What am I doing wrong and how can I get my button color to show up instead of the input-group-addon color?

Comment: can you give us the rest of the relevant css so we have a working demo?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the background of the span explicitly. When an element has no background, the color or image behind it shows through.

Relatedly, there is no `none` value for `background-color`. The default is `transparent`:

[Is background-color:none valid CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739665/is-background-colornone-valid-css)

Answer (score 0):

Try use

```
.input-group .input-group-addon{
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Comment: That will set both input-group-addon and btn-primary to transparent.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to override it back to to the btn-primary properties. The sample below should not affect other style because their styles work together

```
.btn.btn-primary {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #337ab7;
    border-color: #2e6da4;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but I'm allowing the user to theme their bootstrap, so I have no idea what the default button property is...