# Trying to turn off background color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to turn off background-color for twitter-bootstrap. I can do this in inspect element by just crossing it out but how do i do this in the code? I tried doing body{background-color:none;} but its not working for me.

Comment: `none` is not a valid `background-color` value. ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739665/is-background-colornone-valid-css))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tack on `!important` to get the rule to stick:

```css
body {
  background-color: #000 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <div>Test</div>
</body>
```