# React : onMouseEnter / onMouseLeave not working with state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Doing a simple tic-tac-toe game.
I am trying to get a single cell highlighted on mouse-enter and than back to normal on mouse-leave - using state and inline styling to accomplish that.
State changes fine on mouse-enter (so is the styling) however it never sets back to normal on mouse-leave.
What am I missing here?

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Cell(props) {

    let defaultStyle = {backgroundColor: 'none'}
    let selectedStyle = {backgroundColor: 'blue'}


    const [style, setStyle] = useState(defaultStyle)

    const sendData = () =>{
        props.clicker(props.cords)
    }

    const set = () =>{
        setStyle(selectedStyle);

    }

    const unset = () =>{
        setStyle(defaultStyle);
    }

    return (
        <td onClick = {sendData} onMouseEnter= {set} onMouseLeave = {unset} style ={style}>{props.content}</td>
    )
}

export default Cell
```

Comment: `background-color: none` is not part of the CSS standard

Comment: Also, if possible, use CSS instead of JS to simulate the `:hover` pseudo-selector.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is background-color:none valid CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739665/is-background-colornone-valid-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch backgroundColor: 'none' with backgroundColor: 'transparent'

```js
function Cell(props) {

    let defaultStyle = {backgroundColor: 'transparent'}
    let selectedStyle = {backgroundColor: 'blue'}


    const [style, setStyle] = React.useState(defaultStyle)

    const sendData = () =>{
        props.clicker(props.cords)
    }

    const set = () =>{
        setStyle(selectedStyle);

    }

    const unset = () =>{
        setStyle(defaultStyle);
    }

    return (
        <td onClick={sendData} onMouseEnter={set} onMouseLeave={unset} style={style}>{props.content}</td>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Cell clicker={() => {}} cords={() => {}} content='my content' />, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: That did the trick! was under the impression 'none' was a thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`none` is not a valid `background-color`, so React skips it and keeps using the previous style of `blue`. Use something else, like the empty string:

```js
function Cell(props) {

    let defaultStyle = {backgroundColor: ''}
    let selectedStyle = {backgroundColor: 'blue'}


    const [style, setStyle] = React.useState(defaultStyle)

    const sendData = () =>{
        props.clicker(props.cords)
    }

    const set = () =>{
        setStyle(selectedStyle);

    }

    const unset = () =>{
        setStyle(defaultStyle);
    }

    return (
        <div onClick = {sendData} onMouseEnter= {set} onMouseLeave = {unset} style ={style}>{props.content}</div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Cell content='foobar' />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't put a space between '=' and brackets, here is the corrected line :

`<td onClick={sendData} onMouseEnter={set} onMouseLeave={unset} style={style}>{props.content}</td>`

Second, change `{backgroundColor: 'none'}` to `{backgroundColor: 'transparent'}`

Hope you can get your code work :)